# Why is JavaScript function only running once?

Tags: javascript, html

**EDIT:** I realise that I had not included the `name` tags for the inputs being added in. Having done this, I am posting my updated code.

I'm quite new to JavaScript at the moment and I'm trying to run a function to verify some answers when they are submitted by a user, which in turn stylizes the input boxes. This works when I run it once, but when I alter the values and press the submit button again, the function does not run.

Is it possible for the function to be run multiple times?

Here is the function:

```
function checkAnswers1() {

  var ex1q1 = document.forms["ex1"]["exq1"].value;
  var ex1q2 = document.forms["ex1"]["exq2"].value;
  var ex1q3 = document.forms["ex1"]["exq3"].value;
  var ex1q4 = document.forms["ex1"]["exq4"].value;
  var ex1q5 = document.forms["ex1"]["exq5"].value;

  var score = 0;


  if (ex1q1.toLowerCase() == "he will tidy his clothes") {
    score = score + 1;
    document.getElementById("ex1q1").innerHTML = "<div class='form-group has-success has-feedback'><input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + ex1q1 + "' name='ex1q1'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span></div>";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("ex1q1").innerHTML = "<div class='form-group has-error has-feedback'><input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + ex1q1 + "' name='ex1q21'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span></div>";
  }


  if (ex1q2.toLowerCase() == "i shall play in my garden" || ex1q2.toLowerCase() == "i will play in my garden") {
    score = score + 1;
    document.getElementById("ex1q2").innerHTML = "<div class='form-group has-success has-feedback'><input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + ex1q2 + "' name='ex1q2'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span></div>";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("ex1q2").innerHTML = "<div class='form-group has-error has-feedback'><input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + ex1q2 + "' name='ex1q2'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span></div>";
  }


  if (ex1q3.toLowerCase() == "we shall sing with my friends" || ex1q3.toLowerCase() == "we will sing with my friends") {
    score = score + 1;
    document.getElementById("ex1q3").innerHTML = "<div class='form-group has-success has-feedback'><input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + ex1q3 + "' name='ex1q3'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span></div>";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("ex1q3").innerHTML = "<div class='form-group has-error has-feedback'><input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + ex1q3 + "' name='ex1q3'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span></div>";
  }


  if (ex1q4.toLowerCase() == "she will give a gift to him") {
    score = score + 1;
    document.getElementById("ex1q4").innerHTML = "<div class='form-group has-success has-feedback'><input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + ex1q4 + "' name='ex1q4'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span></div>";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("ex1q4").innerHTML = "<div class='form-group has-error has-feedback'><input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + ex1q4 + "' name='ex1q4'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span></div>";
  }


  if (ex1q5.toLowerCase() == "will you speak about your subjects") {
    score = score + 1;
    document.getElementById("ex1q5").innerHTML = "<div class='form-group has-success has-feedback'><input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + ex1q5 + "' name='ex1q5'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span></div>";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("ex1q5").innerHTML = "<div class='form-group has-error has-feedback'><input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + ex1q5 + "' name='ex1q5'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' aria-hidden='true'></span></div>";
  }

  if (score == 5) {
    alert("Well Done! You got 100%");
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("ex1result").innerHTML = "<strong>" + "You scored " + score + "/5" + "</strong>";
  }

}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('submit1').addEventListener('click', checkAnswers1);
});
```

And the HTML is:

```
<form class="form" role="form" name="ex1">
    <ol>
        <li><p>Il rangera ses vêtements</p></li>
        <div id="ex1q1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exq1"><br />
        </div>
        <li><p>Je jouerai dans mon jardin</p></li>
        <div id="ex1q2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exq2"><br />
        </div>
        <li><p>Nous chanterons avec mes copains</p></li>
        <div id="ex1q3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exq3"><br />
        </div>
        <li><p>Elle lui donnera un cadeau</p></li>
        <div id="ex1q4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exq4"><br />
        </div>
        <li><p>Parleravez-vous sur vos matiéres?</p></li>
        <div id="ex1q5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exq5"><br />
        </div>
    </ol>
    <br />
    <div class="text-center">
<button id="submit1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You're overriding all the content of `#ex1q1` in your handler, after that `document.forms['ex1']['exq1']` (and other elements passed to handler) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You replace your names by different values than the originals. In original your first input has name of `exq1`, then you replace it by `ex1q1`. This will not work because the second time your element `exq1` will not exist anymore.

It would be better to not actually replace the `<input>` element, rather put an empty element somewhere next to it and fill it with content if needed.

Comment: Even when I add in the the `name` tags into my innerHTML tags, the function still only runs once.

Comment: Are you using the developer tools (ctrl/cmd+shift+i) ? I suggest you use `console.log` function to see whether your function is called or if it simply does not produce any visible results. Use it to check parameters that are passed to your function etc.

Comment: @josef I tried outputting to my console the value of `ex1q1`. It returns the correct value the first time but when I try to run the function again, I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` as it cannot seem to read the .value of the altered field.

Comment: Hm, please update the question with your new code (the one that adds names to the input tags)

Comment: I have updated the answer. Nevertheless I think you should first simplify your code. For example use only one example question. Also try to share the minimal code that will make us see your whole solution. The code as it is has multiple problems. For example the `ex1result` field does not exist anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving this for me!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to change in your code.
(1) The way you are attaching events is not correct. Use addEventListener to attach events.
(2) Instead of passing the values to `checkAnswers1` read the values from form directly in the method.

With that in mind, I updated your code as follows, such that the click event handler is always called on clicking the button. The event handler method still has errors but I'm sure you can work through them.

```
<form class="form" role="form" name="ex1">
<ol>
    <li><p>Il rangera ses vêtements</p></li>
    <div id="ex1q1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exq1"><br />
    </div>
    <li><p>Je jouerai dans mon jardin</p></li>
    <div id="ex1q2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exq2"><br />
    </div>
    <li><p>Nous chanterons avec mes copains</p></li>
    <div id="ex1q3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exq3"><br />
    </div>
    <li><p>Elle lui donnera un cadeau</p></li>
    <div id="ex1q4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exq4"><br />
    </div>
    <li><p>Parleravez-vous sur vos matiéres?</p></li>
    <div id="ex1q5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exq5"><br />
    </div>
</ol>
<br />
<div class="text-center">
    <button id="submit1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>


function checkAnswers1() {

var ex1q1 = document.forms['ex1']['exq1'].value;
var ex1q2 = document.forms['ex1']['exq2'].value;
var ex1q3 = document.forms['ex1']['exq3'].value;
var ex1q4 = document.forms['ex1']['exq4'].value; 
var ex1q5 = document.forms['ex1']['exq5'].value;
var score = 0;
.
.
.


//Attach event like so 
      document.getElementById('submit1').addEventListener('click', checkAnswers1);
```

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amitrai2000/crw8rbrc/) for full code.